# How do I properly set up my Python dependencies within Jenkins using pip and virtualenv?

Tags: python, jenkins, pip, jenkins-pipeline, virtualenv

I am a rookie to Jenkins trying to set up a Python **pytest** test suite to run. In order to properly execute the test suite, I have to install several Python packages. I'm having trouble with this particular step because Jenkins consistently is unable to find `virtualenv` and `pip`:

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
      gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin/(.*)', defaultValue: 'master', name: 'BRANCH', type: 'PT_BRANCH', quickFilterEnabled: true
    }

    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Checkout source code') {
            steps {

                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '------', url: 'git@github.com:path-to-my-repo/my-test-repo.git']]])
            }
        }

        stage('Start Test Suite') {
            steps {
                    sh script: 'PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/:$PATH'
                    echo "Checking out Test suite repo."

                    sh script: 'virtualenv venv --distribute'
                    sh label: 'install deps', script: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt'
                    sh label: 'execute test suite, exit upon first failure', script: 'pytest --verbose -x --junit-xml reports/results.xml'

                post {
                    always {
                        junit allowEmptyResults: true, testResults: 'reports/results.xml'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

On the `virtualenv venv --distribute` step, Jenkins throws an error (I'm running this initially on a Jenkins server on my local instance, although in production it will be on an Amazon Linux 2 machine):

> - virtualenv venv --distribute /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/my-project-name@tmp/durable-5045c283/script.sh:
>     line 1: virtualenv: command not found

Why is this happening? The step before, I make sure to append where I know my `virtualenv` and `pip` are:

```
 sh script: 'PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/:$PATH'
```

For instance, when I type in

```
sudo su jenkins
which pip
which virtualenv
```

I get the following outputs as expected:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenv

Here are the things I do know:

- Jenkins runs as a user called `jenkins`
- best practice is to create a virtual environment, activate it, and the perform my pip installations inside there
- Jenkins runs `sh` by default, not `bash` (but I'm not sure if this has anything to do with my problem)

Why is Jenkins unable to find my `virtualenv`? What's the best practice for installing Python libraries for a Jenkins build?

**Edit:** I played around some more and found a working solution:

I don't know if this is the proper way to do it, but I used the following syntax:

```
withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/']) {
                            sh script: "pip install virtualenv"
                 // do other setup stuff
    }
```

However, I'm now stuck w/ a new issue: I've clearly hardcoded in my Python path here. If I'm running on a remote Linux machine, am I going to have to install that specific version of Python (3.6)?

Comment: You've tested this _as_ the `jenkins` user?

Comment: Yes? I mean I've tested this by building it in my Jenkins console.

Comment: D'oh. I missed the `sudo su jenkins` bit. :/

Comment: Maybe you should export PATH? Is it processed in another shell?

Comment: `PATH` needs to be exported to the shell environment prior to executing `virtualenv`. You are setting a variable called `$PATH` that is not exported.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I did attempt this, but got the same result. Even when I `echo $PATH` in my pipeline script, I got the valid path, but no success. See my edit above for what did I to get it working.